# how to check if each cells (list) of a column of a dataframe are unique in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a really big data , and what I am trying to do is to check if a list is having  more than one value for a string :
 please consider this dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, 
                      book_id = c("[\"19167120\",\"book\", \"237494310\",\"195166798\",\"book\",\"book.a\"]", 
                                  "[\"19167120\",\"237494310\",\"story\",\"book\",\"19167120\"]", "[]")), 
                 .Names = c("id", "book_id"), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

which is :

```
     id                                                      book_id
1  1 ["19167120","book", "237494310","195166798","book","book.a"]
2  2           ["19167120","237494310","story","book","19167120"]
3  3                                                           []
```

what i am trying to do is to check whether there is any list value from book_id having more than one value of a string , for example here : string value `"19167120"` is duplicate for the second row.
and extract them for each cell and then remove them from each cell

output : two separate dataframe :

```
   id                                                          book_id      duplicate
1:  1 ["19167120", "book", "237494310", "195166798", "book", "book.a"]     "book"
2:  2           ["19167120", "237494310", "story", "book", "19167120"] "19167120"
3:  3                                                               []        0

  id                                                  book_id
1:  1 ["19167120", "book", "237494310", "195166798", "book.a"]
2:  2               ["19167120", "237494310", "story", "book"]
3:  3                                                       []
```

I know I should use `anyduplicated()` and  `unique()` inorder to get my answer but I work around them and I couldn't resolve the problem.

edit :the first suggestion by Gregor will be like this but I would appreciate if any one could help me to get the output as I explain first,

```
id     book_id
1:  1  "19167120"
2:  1 "237494310"
3:  1 "195166798"
4:  2  "19167120"
5:  2 "237494310"
6:  2  "19167120"
> unique(df1)
   id     book_id
1:  1  "19167120"
2:  1 "237494310"
3:  1 "195166798"
4:  2  "19167120"
5:  2 "237494310"
> duplicated(df1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: That's something of an unfortunate data structure. Would you consider changing it so that each row has a single `book_id`?

Comment: thanks @Gregor for your comment, but I would rather want the original format.please see the edit

Comment: thanks for your comment @AnandaMahto,yes, Two new dataframe one having duplicate value as a new column , one removing them.yes that would be easier, in that case is there any straightforward way that after removing the duplicate one I would have the data back to the original format ?

Comment: Both answers here was helpful and good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, related to the idea of starting with a "long" dataset and proceeding from there.

This is your long dataset.

```
library(splitstackshape)
x <- cSplit(df1, "book_id", ",", "long")[, book_id := gsub(
    "[][]", "", book_id)]
```

Here, we add a "duped" column with the duplicated values:

```
x[, duped := paste(unique(book_id[duplicated(book_id)], 
                   collapse = ", ")), by = id]
```

Now we can easily create your first desired output:

```
dupedX <- x[, list(book_id = sprintf("[%s]", paste(book_id, collapse = ", ")),
                   duped = paste(unique(duped), collapse = ", ")), by = id]
dupedX
#    id                                book_id      duped
# 1:  1 ["19167120", "237494310", "195166798"]         NA
# 2:  2  ["19167120", "237494310", "19167120"] "19167120"
# 3:  3                                     []         NA
```

And your second:

```
uniqueX <- x[, list(book_id = sprintf(
  "[%s]", paste(unique(book_id), collapse = ", "))), by = id]
uniqueX
#    id                                book_id
# 1:  1 ["19167120", "237494310", "195166798"]
# 2:  2              ["19167120", "237494310"]
# 3:  3                                     []
```

Comment: Thanks again @Ananda Mahto, your answers do helps a lot!

Comment: @AnandaMahto A doubt about `cSplit_e`. Does it work for `multiple columns` at the same time?

Comment: @AnandaMahto  Yesterday, I answered a question using double `cSplit_e`.  Just checking if there is a better day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693921/generating-binary-variables-in-pig-r/27694291#27694291

Comment: @AnandaMahto, for my own data,after adding duped column I get 50 warnings like this one :In [.data.table(x, , :=(duped, paste(unique(PageFan[duplicated(PageFan)], ... : Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 783 of size 133 in column 'duped' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).? and I change the outputs according to the new dataframe

Answer (score 3):

You could try `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

x <- stri_extract_all_regex(df1$book_id, "\\d+", omit = TRUE)

dupes <- vapply(x, function(a) {
        paste(a[duplicated(a)], collapse = ", ")
    }, "")

dt2 <- data.table(df1, dupes)

doBookId <- function(x) {
    u <-stri_unique(x)
    st <- if(length(u)) toString(shQuote(u, "cmd")) else character(1L)
    stri_c("[", st, "]")
}

dt2[, book_id := vapply(x, doBookId, "")][]
#    id                                book_id    dupes
# 1:  1 ["19167120", "237494310", "195166798"]         
# 2:  2              ["19167120", "237494310"] 19167120
# 3:  3                                     []
```

**Update :** Given your updates, I think we only need a few adjustments.  The main one is to switch from `stri_extract_all_regex` to `stri_extract_all_words`

```
x <- stri_extract_all_words(df1$book_id)
dupes <- vapply(x, function(a) toString(a[duplicated(a)]), "")

dt2 <- data.table(df1, dupes)
dt2
#    id                                                      book_id    dupes
# 1:  1 ["19167120","book", "237494310","195166798","book","book.a"]     book
# 2:  2           ["19167120","237494310","story","book","19167120"] 19167120
# 3:  3                                                           []         

doBookId <- function(x) {
    st <- if(length(x) >= 1L && !is.na(x)) 
        toString(shQuote(unique(x), "cmd"))
    else ""
    stri_c("[", st, "]")
}

dt3 <- dt2[, dupes := NULL]
dt3[, book_id := vapply(x, doBookId, "")][]
#    id                                                  book_id
# 1:  1 ["19167120", "book", "237494310", "195166798", "book.a"]
# 2:  2               ["19167120", "237494310", "story", "book"]
# 3:  3                                                       []
```

Comment: I *think* that what they are looking for is that after your "x", you do something like `vapply(x, function(x) { a <- x[duplicated(x)]; ifelse(length(a) == 0, "0", a) }, character(1L))` for one `data.frame` and `vapply(x, function(x) { sprintf("[%s]", paste(unique(x), collapse = ", ")) }, character(1L))` for another.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Scriven but this is not the answer, sorry for my vague comment on the edit part, I want to have the output as I mention , the edit part work as I mention just fine.

Comment: Richard, go back to [your second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27698588/2) and use my comment if you wish. @academic.user, see the edit that I'm referring to and try the code I shared in the comments.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, I saw the edit part , in your case we will have three duplicate, but mine has just one duplicate.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, thanks for your answer, but it will have a issue when the book_id include a character string "in my own data", and it will change it to numbers,I tried to reproduce the behavior with a small example, but cannot reproduce.but with a different dataframe it give the same data table as before,I change the dataframe which the answer dosen't consider the character string,so you could see the behavior.

Comment: @academic.user - So what do you expect as the result? The same data set?

Comment: @RichardScriven, oh no, I forgot to edit that one , i will change the out put in a minute.

Comment: @academic.user - I've made an update.  Hope it helps